# How to start TimerTask's first task after some time

Tags: android

I have the following TimerTask code:

```
package com.shadow.screentimeout;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.shadow.screentimeout.R;

public class Notification extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Timer timer;
Toast toast;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

timer = new Timer();
toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 seconds after",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
{
@Override
public void run() {
toast.show();
Log.v("ScreenTimeOut","Toast showed");
}
}, 0, 10000);
}
}
```

I want to get the toast after 10 seconds after the activity is called/started and the next toast message after 10 seconds from the first one an so on.

But whenever the activity is called/started, I get the first toast message as soon as the activity is started.
I want the first message after 10 seconds.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are scheduling with a delay of 0. Change to this:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        toast.show();
        Log.v("ScreenTimeOut","Toast showed");
    }
}, 10000, 10000);  // First 10000 is delay
```